# Java modify array elemens

Tags: java, arrays

Hey guys I want to write  program that shifts elements in an array once to the left but I tried everything and it's not working. The code below is outputting just 0's. Can someone please tell me how I can do this. Thank you!

`````
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class StudentScores {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
      int[] oldScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int[] newScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < oldScores.length; ++i) {
         oldScores[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }

      int temp = newScores[0];
      for (i = 0; i < oldScores.length - 1; ++i) {
           newScores[i] = newScores[i+1];
      }
       temp = newScores[oldScores.length - 1];
         
      for (i = 0; i < newScores.length; ++i) {
         System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}````
`````

Comment: `newScores[i] = newScores[i+1];` should probably be `newScores[i] = oldScores[i+1];`

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you tried to do with the `temp` variable. Did you want to make the first element of the old array the last element of the new array?

Comment: thanks that solved most of the problem, but the last element is outputting to 0 instead of the first element coming to the end. For example if I input {10, 20, 30, 40} its outputting, {20,30,40,0}.

Comment: you only need a temp value if you operate on a single array. the old array will still be there. also the first element of `oldScores` will always be 0, because you increment `i` prematurely.

Comment: sorry but its still outputting 0 at the end

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by people in comments, you seem to be assigning `newScores[]` to `newScores[]` value(an uninitialized array has all values set to 0):

```java
int temp = newScores[0]; // Should be oldScores[0]

// ...

newScores[i] = newScores[i+1]; // Should be oldScores[i+1]
```

You need to have `oldScores[]` values on RHS. Since you only want to shift by one place, I think extra array is unnecessary. You can do it in place like this:

```java
int temp = oldScores[0];
for (i = 0; i < oldScores.length - 1; ++i) {
   oldScores[i] = oldScores[i + 1];
}
oldScores[oldScores.length - 1] = temp;
```

Comment: @Sainathi: polite ping, Would it be possible for you to mark this answer as accepted if this resolved your issue_/\_?